# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 - Merge Replication Identity Management Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, replication

Accidental DBA here.   I am managing a merge replication and the Identity Management fields are not updating with new ranges and are constantly needing me to reseed or run sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange.  I have noticed the following oddities:

1. When running DBCC CHECKIDENT([tablename]) the current identity value is a lot smaller than the current column value
2. When running DBCC CHECKIDENT([tablename]), sometimes the current identity value is set to under 100 when the Current Identity Value is 500,000 plus.  But it will do it more than once with the same number.
3. The MSarticles in the distribution database is empty as well as the MSrepl_identity_range (I kind of thought that this should have the ranges in it, no?)
4. Sometimes it's the code throwing the error that the identity range is incorrect and a simple refresh fixes it.
5. The sync is run every 4 hours (which seems a bit long to me as I was used to running the sync more often at last job)

I was thinking I could run sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange in a job in the agent every hour in between syncs to fix this, but it seems to easy.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Also, if anyone knows a really great book on replication, troubleshooting replication, and fixing replication that would be helpful.

Comment: Identities can get iffy.  Check this link.  It shows that it can return different values running the same command.  Make sure you use the `noReSeed` unless you want your check to automatically reseed so the identity and column match.  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/the-nuance-of-dbcc-checkident-that-drives-me-crazy/

Comment: Thanks for the link.   I also did not realize this.